# Count number of orders by a customer with amount less than the present order value in the last two orders in SQL?

Tags: sql, pyspark, window-functions, impala

**Consider that I have a table**

| Customer | Day | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 96 |
| A | 22 | 63 |
| A | 32 | 19 |
| A | 50 | 27 |
| A | 57 | 99 |
| A | 72 | 93 |
| B | 69 | 97 |
| B | 82 | 22 |
| B | 87 | 64 |
| C | 22 | 60 |
| C | 30 | 22 |
| C | 48 | 74 |
| C | 49 | 68 |
| C | 55 | 11 |
| C | 85 | 79 |

I need to calculate the number of orders for every customer whose value is **less than the order value of the present order** among his past two orders, i.e

| Customer | Day | Amount | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 96 | 0 |
| A | 22 | 63 | 0 |
| A | 32 | 19 | 0 |
| A | 50 | 27 | 1 |
| A | 57 | 99 | 2 |
| A | 72 | 93 | 1 |
| B | 69 | 97 | 0 |
| B | 82 | 22 | 0 |
| B | 87 | 64 | 1 |
| C | 22 | 60 | 0 |
| C | 30 | 22 | 0 |
| C | 48 | 74 | 2 |
| C | 49 | 68 | 1 |
| C | 55 | 11 | 0 |
| C | 85 | 79 | 2 |

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only `PRECEEDING` 2 ROWS , you can pre-compute the `LAG` values and utilise a `CASE` statement to generate the required logic.

**Else if you want it to be more dynamic and flexible in nature you can utilise Shubham Sharma's answer**

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
Customer    Day Amount
A   4   96
A   22  63
A   32  19
A   50  27
A   57  99
A   72  93
B   69  97
B   82  22
B   87  64
C   22  60
C   30  22
C   48  74
C   49  68
C   55  11
C   85  79
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='\t')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+--------+---+------+
|Customer|Day|Amount|
+--------+---+------+
|       A|  4|    96|
|       A| 22|    63|
|       A| 32|    19|
|       A| 50|    27|
|       A| 57|    99|
|       A| 72|    93|
|       B| 69|    97|
|       B| 82|    22|
|       B| 87|    64|
|       C| 22|    60|
|       C| 30|    22|
|       C| 48|    74|
|       C| 49|    68|
|       C| 55|    11|
|       C| 85|    79|
+--------+---+------+
```

#### SparkSQL

```
sparkDF.registerTempTable("TB1")

sql.sql("""
SELECT
    CUSTOMER,
    DAY,
    AMOUNT,
    CASE 
        WHEN AMOUNT > LAG_1 AND AMOUNT > LAG_2 THEN 2
        WHEN AMOUNT > LAG_1 OR AMOUNT > LAG_2 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as Count
FROM (
    SELECT
        CUSTOMER,
        DAY,
        AMOUNT,
        LAG(AMOUNT,1) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY DAY) as lag_1,
        LAG(AMOUNT,2) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY DAY) as lag_2
    FROM TB1
)
ORDER BY 1,2
;
""").show()

+--------+---+------+-----+
|CUSTOMER|DAY|AMOUNT|Count|
+--------+---+------+-----+
|       A|  4|    96|    0|
|       A| 22|    63|    0|
|       A| 32|    19|    0|
|       A| 50|    27|    1|
|       A| 57|    99|    2|
|       A| 72|    93|    1|
|       B| 69|    97|    0|
|       B| 82|    22|    0|
|       B| 87|    64|    1|
|       C| 22|    60|    0|
|       C| 30|    22|    0|
|       C| 48|    74|    2|
|       C| 49|    68|    1|
|       C| 55|    11|    0|
|       C| 85|    79|    2|
+--------+---+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the way to convert table data provided here into a dataframe

Comment: yeah , `StringIO` is quiet useful

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with when otherwise and lag

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
schema="Customer string,day int,Amount int"

data=[('A',4,96),('A',22,63),('A',32,19),('A',50,27),('A',57,99),('A',72,93),('B',69,97),('B',82,22),('B',87,64),('C',22,60),('C',30,22),('C',48,74),('C',49,68),('C',55,11),('C',85,79)]
dql=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
dql.withColumn("count",when((col('Amount')>F.lag("Amount",2).over(Window.partitionBy("Customer").orderBy("day"))) & (col('Amount')>F.lag("Amount",1).over(Window.partitionBy("Customer").orderBy("day"))) ,2).when((col('Amount')>F.lag("Amount",2).over(Window.partitionBy("Customer").orderBy("day"))) | (col('Amount')>F.lag("Amount",1).over(Window.partitionBy("Customer").orderBy("day"))) ,1).otherwise("0")).show()

#output
+--------+---+------+-----+
|Customer|day|Amount|count|
+--------+---+------+-----+
|       A|  4|    96|    0|
|       A| 22|    63|    0|
|       A| 32|    19|    0|
|       A| 50|    27|    1|
|       A| 57|    99|    2|
|       A| 72|    93|    1|
|       B| 69|    97|    0|
|       B| 82|    22|    0|
|       B| 87|    64|    1|
|       C| 22|    60|    0|
|       C| 30|    22|    0|
|       C| 48|    74|    2|
|       C| 49|    68|    1|
|       C| 55|    11|    0|
|       C| 85|    79|    2|
+--------+---+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us use [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#collect_list) over `Window` to collect the amounts corresponding to past two orders, then [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) to count the values in list which are less than `Amount` in current row

```
w = Window.partitionBy('Customer').orderBy('Day').rowsBetween(-2, -1)

df.withColumn(
    'Count',
    F.aggregate(
        F.collect_list('Amount').over(w), F.lit(0),
        lambda acc, x: acc + (x < F.col('Amount')).cast('int')
    )
)
```

---

```
+--------+---+------+-----+
|Customer|Day|Amount|Count|
+--------+---+------+-----+
|       A|  4|    96|    0|
|       A| 22|    63|    0|
|       A| 32|    19|    0|
|       A| 50|    27|    1|
|       A| 57|    99|    2|
|       A| 72|    93|    1|
|       B| 69|    97|    0|
|       B| 82|    22|    0|
|       B| 87|    64|    1|
|       C| 22|    60|    0|
|       C| 30|    22|    0|
|       C| 48|    74|    2|
|       C| 49|    68|    1|
|       C| 55|    11|    0|
|       C| 85|    79|    2|
+--------+---+------+-----+
```